# mclr reset the system pic with #pragma

Tags: c, pic, mplab

I have this ISR:

```
static void ButtonDebounce(void)
{    
   static uint16_t debounceCounter = 0;
    // Check if only one S3 or s4 button pressed since if I have bouncing several
   // interrupts will occur and will result on several resets on board.

    if ((BUTTON_IsPressed( BUTTON_S3 ) == true) || (BUTTON_IsPressed( BUTTON_S4 ) == true)){
      if(debounceCounter == 0)
      {
        LED_Toggle( LED_D4 ); //Led blinks when Btn3 or Btns4 is pressed.
        if (BUTTON_IsPressed( BUTTON_S3 ) == true){
            //__asm__ volatile ("reset"); // soft-reset is not the better choice
            #pragma config WDT=ON // Enable WDT. The safer way to implement 
            // reset on the system is via WDT since this timer is resetting the whole
            // board and not only the Microcontroller.
            // Page 43 - MPLAB_XC16_C_Compiler_Users_Guide.pdf
            while(1){} // Just wait for wdt to reset the system.
        }
        else if (BUTTON_IsPressed( BUTTON_S4 ) == true){
            printf("Avg Temp = %4f\r\n Avg Hmdt = %4f\r\n Min Temp = %4d\r\n Max Temp = %4d\r\n Min Hmdt = %4d\r\n Max Hmdt = %4d\r\n", 
                    calculateAvgTemp(), calculateAvgHumidity(), calculateMinTemp(), 
                    calcuateMaxTemp(), calculateMinHumidity(), calcuateMaxHumidity());
        }
    }        
    debounceCounter = BUTTON_DEBOUCE_TIME_MS;
} else{
    if(debounceCounter != 0)
    {
        debounceCounter--;
    }
 }
}
```

But I get: main.c: In function 'ButtonDebounce':
main.c:102:25: error: unknown configuration setting: 'WDT'

Any suggestion?

Comment: What is the device model? `#pragma config` lines don't belong to functions. They control the config bytes of the PIC and they are project wide. Best place for them is main.c or some dedicated include file. I often place them into a config.h and include it in main.c

Comment: Write to the register that enables `WDT`, not a `#pragma config`...